# Excluding certain text in xpath/echo (php)?

Tags: php, xpath, hide

Doing some tests and wondering the best way to go about removing some unwanted text during a xpath/echo. The below php code is spitting out the result below

```
// stock trebnds
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;



$doc>
 loadHTMLFile('https://www.bloomberg.com/research/sectorandindustry/
overview/sectorlanding.asp');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//table[@id='sectorTable']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces


}
```

Updated: 4:01pm ETSector Performance Price perEarnings(TTM) Price toSales (TTM) DividendYield 1 Month 3 Month YTD Consumer Discretionary17 Industries-0.42%+4.71%+10.52%16.5x1.0x1.27%Consumer Staples9 Industries+2.85%+3.33%+8.58%15.1x1.0x2.86%Energy3 Industries-2.24%-5.67%-13.57%14.0x1.2x1.74%Financials12 Industries+2.36%-1.53%+3.77%15.2x2.1x1.91%Health Care8 Industries+2.52%+2.85%+13.12%18.2x1.2x1.86%Industrials17 Industries+1.01%+3.55%+7.21%15.7x1.1x1.85%Information Technology10 Industries+1.41%+7.36%+18.03%14.8x2.1x0.90%Materials6 Industries+3.26%+4.63%+8.91%13.2x1.1x1.79%Telecommunication Services3 Industries+1.08%-4.79%-8.36%22.6x1.3x4.83%Utilities6 Industries+4.33%+6.29%+9.34%17.1x1.3x3

Anyone know some code I can insert that basically will remove anything I want in what the php is "spitting out?" For ex, say I want to remove the first line, "Updated: 4:01pm ETSector Performance Price perEarnings(TTM) Price toSales (TTM) DividendYield"

I assume there's some sort of, hide text function in php.

Thanks for any thoughts on this!!

Comment: The best idea I've come up with is using something like this. while it's not ideal because there are certain situations where there might be tags used multiple times, it might get rid of somethings. I don't know how to make it work with the above code though: strip_tags($html, '<span><span class><td><th><thead><tbody><tfoot>');

Comment: Another idea is using this to remove specific keywords, though I'm not able to get it to function with the above code. echo str_replace("UPDATED", "", "REGISTER UPDATED here");

Comment: the above would probably be the simplest solution